# Git pull command with AWK

Tags: awk

I want to store the git pull command into output.log file, i want to take the only files not full path starting line of folder name.

Actual output

```
Updating ca4e3bd..82ac123
Fast-forward
build.yaml                                                     | 121 ++++------------------------------------------------------
packages/POC1/ns/POC1/testFlow2/flow.xml     |   4 ++
packages/POC1/ns/POC1/testFlow2/flow.xml.bak |   4 ++
packages/POC1/ns/POC1/testFlow2/node.ndf     |  42 ++++++++++++++++++++
packages/POC2/ns/POC2/testFlow1/flow.xml     |   4 ++
packages/POC2/ns/POC2/testFlow1/flow.xml.bak |   4 ++
packages/POC2/ns/POC2/testFlow1/node.ndf     |  42 ++++++++++++++++++++
packages/POC2/poc2.txt                                |   0
8 files changed, 107 insertions(+), 114 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 packages/POC1/ns/POC1/testFlow2/flow.xml
create mode 100644 packages/POC1/ns/POC1/testFlow2/flow.xml.bak
create mode 100644 packages/POC1/ns/POC1/testFlow2/node.ndf
create mode 100644 packages/POC2/ns/POC2/testFlow1/flow.xml
create mode 100644 packages/POC2/ns/POC2/testFlow1/flow.xml.bak
create mode 100644 packages/POC2/ns/POC2/testFlow1/node.ndf
create mode 100644 packages/POC2/poc2.tx
```

my command

```
awk -F/  '{ print $4 }' out.log1



POC1
POC1
POC1
POC2
POC2
POC2


POC1
POC1
POC1
POC2
POC2
POC2
```

Expected output i want to like this

```
POC1
POC1
POC1
POC2
POC2
POC2
```

```
awk -F / 'NF >= 4 {print $4}' out.log1
POC1
POC1
POC1
POC2
POC2
POC2
POC1
POC1
POC1
POC2
POC2
POC2
```

Comment: Using slash as the field separator, it seems you should skip lines without at least 4 fields: `NF >= 4 {print $4}`

Comment: it would make more sense to actually use git to give you the information you need than trying to parse it out from the human-audience output of `git pull`.

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller I agree with you but based on git pull command output i want get the files then later i have to later point during the pipeline build

Comment: Hi @glennjackman do you mean like this awk -F NF >=4  '{ print $4 }' out.log1?

Comment: No, `awk -F/ 'NF >= 4 {print $4}'`

Comment: Can you please i have updated output based on your command, this is not working awk -F / 'NF >= 4 {print $4}' out.log1

Comment: @viswa whether you do the strange awk parsing or ask git for the list of files that changed makes not a difference. You can do it anytime and safe the result to a text file.